# iPhone Web App - Disable body scrolling but allow on all elements within body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone-web-app

I am currently using the following code to disable the html and body from scrolling:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

This works but it disables all native scrolling within the page. I have seen many topics about this on this website but I have not seen a clear answer or example of it allowing scrolling on any other element within the page without having to define one.

Can you just disable the elasticity of the scrolling and then scroll the body with -webkit-overflow scrolling?

If anyone knows an efficient way to do this I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to use css?

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBuhy/